# A counterexample to $\lim$ and $\int$ interversion

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

We have the following theorem:

> If $[a,b]\subset \mathbb R$ and $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence of integrable functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb R$. Assuming $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges uniformly to $f$.
>
> Then $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and
>
> $$\int_a^b f=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_a^b f_n.$$

I know that this theorem is false when we replace $[a,b]$ with $[1,\infty)$.

So I was looking for a counterexample in that particular case, but I didn't find any. Do you think of one ?

Comment: If there exists a number $L$ such that $f_n(x)$ is also continuous for all $x>L$, then the interchange of operators is legitimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the example
\begin{align}
f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\chi_{[1, n+1]}
\end{align}
which converges uniformly to $0$, but the integrals for the $f_n$ are always $1$ which mean the limit is also $1$ and not $0$.